# getting an error when installing chakra ui on react js

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I installed chakra-ui in React js, and when I setup index js to place ChakraProvider I got an error on the  framer motion
`TypeError: framer_motion__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.motion.custom is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an error, because of the frammer-motion version. Please downgrade your "framer-motion".

1. open package.json
2. change = "framer-motion": "^4.1.1", to "framer-motion": "^3.1.1",
3. npm/yarn install again.